# Using ROSBridge Between Two Processes on the Same Computer

Tags: c#, c++, tcp, websocket, ros

I have a C++ ROS node using ROSBridge to send the ROS Topics as JSON strings via TCP WebSocket over port 9090. On the same computer, I have a C# Unity program that needs to access the JSON and send some of its own. If I put this program on a different computer there is no problem--I can access port 9090 and see the JSON. But if it is on the same computer as the ROSBridge Host, then there is a conflict with using the same port. So the two applications cannot communicate with each other on the same PC but they can on separate PCs.

So what can I do? Must the ports match and thus always conflict or maybe I can somehow make Process A send on 9090 but receive on 9091 and Process B just the opposite or something? Any other options? In essence, I'm trying to get Unity to participate in the ROS communications, but it does not have native support for that and thus the workaround with the ROSBridge JSON strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like my understanding about ports was lacking. The host for the ROSBridge is being set up to use port 9090 so that anyone wishing to connect to it will request the host's port 9090 for the connection but will still use whatever port it desires on its own side. In both applications, I can state that the "Host" port is 9090 without conflict because the client application will still open a random other port for its own use to connect to the host port. Therefore, the trouble I am experiencing is something other than "port sharing" since that is not what is happening. Only one is hosting on 9090.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite/Tutorials/RunningRosbridge you can set the port that Rosbridge talks on in the `.launch` file.

If you are using the example `rosbridge_websocket.launch` file, the second line of the file includes a port number in the form of `<arg name="port" default="9090" />`.
You can change `9090` to change the default port it uses.

---

According to the `roslaunch` documentation at http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools you can also pass arguments to `roslaunch` on the command line:

The `rosbridge_websocket.launch` file sets the port from the argument "port", so if you run roslaunch like this it will use port 8080:

`roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch port:=8080`

---

You can see the full rosbridge_websocket.launch file at https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/blob/develop/rosbridge_server/launch/rosbridge_websocket.launch

Looking over that file for the line `<param name="port" value="$(arg port)"/>` is how I know that it uses the "port" argument to set the port.

---

If you post your `.launch` files I can give your more advice on how to edit them if this answer is not clear.

Comment: Hey Chris. This doesn't change the inherent problem with two processes accessing the same port. If I tell the RosBridge to use port 8080 instead of 9090, then I still have to tell my second process to use 8080 instead of 9090 and they're now both using the same port again. If I leave process 2 on 9090, then they'll never connect.

Comment: Am I simply misunderstanding how sockets work? Can the two processes have different sockets and still somehow manage to communicate?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Yes, I think you are misunderstanding something. Only the SERVER needs to be on a known port. The client will talk to that port to get data. The client does use a port, but it just picks an empty port when it starts.
Even if both sides have a port, the port you set is always the LISTENING port. So if one listens on 9090 and the other on 8080, then they can coexist, and both talk to each other. Again, when they talk, they will use a different port from the port they listen on.
My guess is you only need one of these two to listen, but I don't know which.

Comment: @CodeMonkey When you tell Unity how to talk to Rosbridge, what is the format of the address?

It cold be that you just need to add the port number to the address to tell Unity to call out on a different port, and then put Rosbridge on that port.

Comment: Okay, in the Unity app I select an IP and a port for the "host" that it connects to. So maybe I still say 9090 for that but that's not necessarily the one that it, itself, is using. I tried swapping which computers I was using and it might not be a problem with a shared port like I was thinking. Unity still couldn't seem to get out to the network on that particular (Ubuntu) machine. So I think I'm missing some kind of permissions for it. No clue what though! Unity can connect from another machine coming in, but just not on that machine going out.

Comment: When you run both Rosbridge and Unity on the same host, the IP Unity connects to should be 127.0.0.1 and yes, just use the port 9090 as usual.